# Storyboard and preview not matching

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Trying to setup the Scroll View but what shows in the Storyboard and the Preview is not the same as what shows on the Phone or the simulator.

I am currently on XCode version Version 6.1 (6A1052d)

Is this a bug?  Am I doing something wrong here?  Is anyone experiencing this sort of discrepency?

Thanks all,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Fogmeister.  I just wasn't searching for the right terminology.  That said, the answer was there but how to implement it was not.  I added that here and will add it to the linked answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, edited answer:

You have a scroll view that is constrained to the top layout guide! Then, your view controller also has the "Adjust scroll view insets"-parameter checked. This will render the content inset being 64px.

Try constraining the scrollviews top to the superview instead of the top layout guide OR change your navigation bar from/to translucent.

Comment: Thanks Spoek.  I have tried this a number of ways including the suggestion you made and it just hasn't panned out.  That said, it would seem that I wasn't specific enough in my search to have come across the article mentioned by Fogmeister.  I will post the answer above.